# Cannot write white spaces in a Alert object in ipyvuetify

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I try to display n progress bar in an Alert (instead of using the vuetify progress element I know).

I created a little script that does a nice output as a str :

```py
def update_progress(progress, msg='Progress', bar_length=30):
    plain_char = '█'
    empty_char = ' '
    progress = float(progress)
    block = int(round(bar_length * progress))

    text = f'{msg}: |{plain_char * block + empty_char * (bar_length - block)}| {progress *100:.1f}%'
    
    return text
```

when I print the output, I get the following :
[image: Capture d’écran 2020-11-12 à 11 18 26]

and when I insert it as a child in an Alert component :
[image: Capture d’écran 2020-11-12 à 11 19 09]

First problem, the spaces have been trimed, second problem it's changing the block ascii character to a wider one.
Is it normal and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced in the github repository of the ipyvuetify lib ([#103](https://github.com/mariobuikhuizen/ipyvuetify/issues/103)), it's a 'feature' of HTML: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Using the pre tag will preserve whitespace:

```py
v.Html(
    tag='pre', 
    children=['a                 mess age'], 
    class_='info--text',
    style_='font-family:roboto'
)
```

The `class` and `style` traitlets are here to keep the formating of the Alert (need to be adapted to your own `type_`)